# Why do they check WeakReference for null?

Tags: android, multithreading, image, android-asynctask, weak-references

Here is the blog post on android developers on how download images asynchronously:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

The code snippet from it:

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
         // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
         return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question:
Why do they check imageViewReference for null? Is that an misspell?

Comment: i don't see any good reason. you can safely remove it.

Comment: WeakReference can be easily GC

Comment: @njzk2 is right - it is even declared final, so it MUST be assigned in an initializer or constructor - else it wouldn't even compile - and nothing is allowed to change its assignment, so it can't ever be null.

Comment: @blackbelt : the ref inside the WR can be GCed, hence the need to test the value returned by WR.get, but the WR object itself is like any object, it cannot disappear like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like really stale code. Remove this check, nothing bad should happen.