# Do I need to check a WeakReference inside an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I'm using the following pattern taken from the Android developers docs:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is this:  why do we need to check if `imageViewReference` is null at the start of `onPostExecute()`?  Since it's assigned in the constructor there shouldn't be any way for it to be null at this point.  I do understand verifying the return of the `get()` call to verify that the underlying `ImageView` is still around.  Thanks.

Comment: your understanding is correct. any statement of the form `variable = new Object()` result in `variable` being a strong reference to that object (unless a throwable is thrown during the constructor), until it is explicitely set to something else.

Comment: @Kasra, thanks, but the question wasn't about the referent stored in the WeakReference but the WeakReference object itself.  I just found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336544/why-do-they-check-weakreference-for-null?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't check `imageViewReference` for `null`, you should check for `null` only what it covers - `ImageView` using the return value of `get` method.

Comment: Thanks!  I hesitate to second-guess code samples on the developer site.

Answer (score 1):

John you are correct there is no need to do it.